# Sending custom data to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, samsung-smart-tv

I've been developing a Smart TV app and integrated google analytics. Now I can see number of page view etc. But what i actually want to do is to send a custom data string to google analytics and control `"assetid"` variable. I want to track number of contents whose `"assetid"` var is 0.

A sample custom data below:
`assetid=11031&type=vod&sessionid=me7ujh7kqemg9jkqegh80cjtv2&checksum=4574d2362e51a398086a6e8ff87de447`

Do i need to convert it to JSON or Array and what should i do to track it on google analytics?

Comment: send it as a custom dimension? or several custom dimensions? How are you sending the data initially?

Comment: All I have done is that I generated google analytics tracking code and put it in my .html file. I am not currently sending any data belong to my contents.

Comment: Nice last I knew adding the tracking code to smart tv didn't work. I think this is what you are looking for https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an application for Google Analytics' [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)

That gives you a format to craft URL that will send into GA what you are asking.  You can use your sessionid to GA's cid to match users over multiple sessions.

It works by making a simple POST to Google Analytics, which you can load with events or custom dimensions that match your needs of the Smart TV.  [Dev guide here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide)